# How do I create Varnish cache objects for certain pages without a "first user"?

Tags: varnish

We have some pages that take forever to load and are not hit very often.  If we set `set beresp.ttl = 5d;` for those pages in the .vcl file, how can we also force a new cached object, so that object is not created on the fly when a user gets the page, say, 20 days later?

In other words, I want to cache a certain group of pages without a "first user", if that's possible through varnish itself.  Otherwise, I suppose we just run a script that hits each of the pages.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in caching warming in Varnish. However, you could scan your sitemap or create a list of important pages and call these in a cronjob on a daily basis, ensuring these objects are in the cache when they need to be.

Of course, as you mentioned, the TTL needs to be high enough to keep these objects around.

You can also set the grace value extremely high through `set beresp.grace=1y;`, which will serve expired content while Varnish asynchronously fetches the most recent version, as long as there's grace time left.

Grace will take a away the pain of revalidation, however the object needs to be in the cache in the first place before grace can be leveraged.